# Share Memory Error: shmat return NULL ,errno(22:Invalid argument) in CentOS6.8

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

This is I waited two file for share memory ,one is written data to share memory,another is read data from share memory and printf datas; but there are something error.

shm_w.c

```
#include  <stdio.h>

#include  <sys/shm.h>

#include  <string.h>

#define  MAX_MEM 4096




int main()
{

    int shmid;
    int ret;
    void* mem;

    shmid=shmget(0x12367,MAX_MEM,IPC_CREAT | 0666 );
    printf("shmid is = %d,pid=%d\n",shmid,getpid());
    mem=shmat(shmid,(const void*)0,0);
    if((int)mem==-1)
    {
            printf("attach faile.\n");
    }

    strcpy((char*)mem,"Hello,this is test memory.\n");

    ret=shmdt(mem);

return 0;

}
```

shm_r.c

```
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/shm.h>

#include <string.h>

#define MAX_MEM 4096



int main()

{

        int shmid;
        int ret;
        void* mem;

        shmid=shmget(0x12367,MAX_MEM,0);
        mem=shmat(shmid,(const void*)0,0);
        //printf("%s\n",(char*)mem);
        if(mem==(void*)-1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"shmat return NULL ,errno(%d:%s)\n",errno,strerror(errno));
            return 2;
        }
        printf("%s\n",(char*)mem);

        shmdt(mem);

return 0;



}
```

When I in CentOS6.8 compile two .c files, the first time is ok.

Unfortunately, from now on ,I runed she_w.c was right too:

shmid is = 65537,pid=7116.

but when I run shm_r.c , it's appear error:

---

> shmat return NULL ,errno(22:Invalid argument)

---

so I didn't know what happen it ? I try to solve it ,for example used ipcs -m ,but not appear the shmid.
   And I cat /proc/7116/maps :
    "No such file or directory"

who can tell me what happen ? And How can I find shmid in CentOS6.6

```
uname -r: 
2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64
```

I also use cat /proc/sysvipc/shm | grep 65537, but not appear the shmid.
   Bad luck!

Please tell me how to solve the problem if you know ,thanks!

Comment: `(const void*)0` - use the `NULL` macro to get a _null pointer constant_.

Comment: Are you running these two programs one after the other?  What do you think will happen when the first program detaches the memory segment before the other program starts? You need to wait for the other program to run before you can detach the segment.

Comment: "Are you running these two programs one after the other? What do you think will happen when the first program detaches the memory segment before the other program starts? You need to wait for the other program to run before you can detach the segment."                                            Why must detached after read program and can't  detached at write program ?  I means the write program write data is over, it's can detached, I don't know why when write program complete can use detach. if I used detached in write program, the share memory will free ,so read program can't read data ?

Comment: You need to make a System V IPC key using the ftok function and pass that key in shmget. Look at this tutorial, https://www.softprayog.in/programming/interprocess-communication-using-system-v-shared-memory-in-linux.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If the writer is run first, it creates the segment [and detaches/terminates]. This is fine. SysV IPC shared memory segments _persist_--`shmdt` doesn't delete the segment and the segment retains data just like a file would. To delete a segment requires `shmctl(...,IPC_RMID,NULL)`

Comment: @kjohri While `ftok` gives back a key value that is likely to not conflict/collide, it isn't _required_ to use it. Picking a sufficiently obscure key value is fine for testing. The active list of keys can be checked via `ipcs`. This is probably not OP's problem, since he was able to run successfully the _first_ time (i.e. no collision with some _other_ program).

Comment: @Craig Estey  today I runed it was successful, but each time shmid was same, of course run writer first , I don't know why was successful today and last night was filed; I seem about reboot OS problems , always I think share memory been writed data by process, the process can be leave and the share memory has not  nothing process attached ,still normal.So, I don't explain last night why it was fail ,it was strange.

Comment: If you reboot the OS, the segments disappear, so you get a "clean slate". I can't say for sure what happened on your system when it failed, but I believe it was covered in the discussion in my answer. I've done plenty of shm implementations and the errors usually fall into those categories.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded and run your program and am unable to reproduce your [conflicting] results.

To list the active shm segments, use the `ipcs` command. If you needed to delete the one you created, you can use the `ipcrm` command.

There are two things I can think of that *might* be an issue for you, but I'm discounting them because you said that you ran successfully the *first* time.

The permissions on the segment because you created it incorrectly the first time. `ipcs` should show this.

When you were debugging your writer program, it may have done something incorrectly. This can be seen with `ipcs`. If a mistake was made, you can manually remove the segment with `ipcrm` and try your program again.

The other possibility is that your key collides with some other segment created by another program. This is unlikely for two reasons.

Your key is, in all probably unique. This can also be checked with `ipcs`

Most programs nowadays use a key of 0x00000000 which is the "private" mode. This is done when a program does a `fork` but does *not* do an `execvp`. The child just calls some function (e.g. `child_worker`). The parent and child communicate data back and forth using the "private" segment. Since the segment is private, you don't have to worry about having a unique key value.

Because you have two separate programs, using that mode would *not* work for your use case. You need a non-zero key value so your segment will *persist* from one program invocation to the next.

---

For simplicity, I combined both your programs into a single one. I also added an option to delete the shm segment.

*Note:* I did cosmetic cleanup only. I did *not* fix any bugs. So, this is just an FYI for what I tested on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_MEM 4096
#define XID     0x12367

int opt_cmd;

void
writer(void)
{
    int shmid;
    void *mem;

    shmid = shmget(XID,MAX_MEM,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    printf("shmid is = %d,pid=%d\n",shmid,getpid());
    mem = shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
    if (mem == (void *) -1) {
        printf("attach faile.\n");
    }

    strcpy((char *) mem,"Hello,this is test memory.\n");

    shmdt(mem);
}

void
reader(void)
{
    int shmid;
    void *mem;

    shmid = shmget(XID,MAX_MEM,0);
    mem = shmat(shmid,NULL,0);

    // printf("%s\n",(char*)mem);
    if (mem == (void *) -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"shmat return NULL ,errno(%d:%s)\n",
            errno,strerror(errno));
        exit(2);
    }

    printf("%s\n",(char *) mem);

    shmdt(mem);
}

void
clean(void)
{
    int shmid;

    shmid = shmget(XID,MAX_MEM,0);
    shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL);
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (; argc > 0; --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'd':
        case 'w':
        case 'r':
            opt_cmd = cp[1];
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (opt_cmd) {
    case 'w':
        writer();
        break;

    case 'd':
        clean();
        break;

    default:
        reader();
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you run this without args (or without first running with "-w") it will fail with "shmat return NULL ,errno(22:Invalid argument)". Is this expected? shmat fails unless something has written to the shared memory first? I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

For using the shmget () call, it is necessary to include `<sys/ipc.h>`.

shm_w.c

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include  <sys/shm.h>
#include  <string.h>

#define  MAX_MEM 4096

int main()
{

    int shmid;
    int ret;
    void* mem;

    shmid=shmget(0x12367,MAX_MEM,IPC_CREAT | 0666 );
    printf("shmid is = %d,pid=%d\n",shmid,getpid());
    mem=shmat(shmid,(const void*)0,0);
    if(mem==(void *) -1)
    {
            printf("attach faile.\n");
    }

    strcpy((char*)mem,"Hello,this is test memory.\n");

    ret=shmdt(mem);

    return 0;

}
```

shm_r.c

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include  <sys/shm.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_MEM 4096

int main()

{

        int shmid;
        int ret;
        void* mem;

        shmid=shmget(0x12367,MAX_MEM,0);
        mem=shmat(shmid,(const void*)0,0);
        //printf("%s\n",(char*)mem);
        if(mem==(void *) -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"shmat return NULL ,errno(%d:%s)\n",errno,strerror(errno));
            return 2;
        }
        printf("%s\n",(char*)mem);

            shmdt(mem);

    return 0;
    }

    $ gcc shm_w.c -o shm_w
    $ gcc shm_r.c -o shm_r
    $ ./shm_w
    shmid is = 2293774,pid=5779
    $ ./shm_r
    Hello,this is test memory.

    $ ./shm_r
    Hello,this is test memory.

    $ ./shm_r
    Hello,this is test memory.
```